# First angular $http POST falls to .then error path even though REST call succeds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am seeing something weird. This happen only on the first instance of the POST call. Subsequent repeat requests (when the form is re-submitted) work just fine.

The first $http post falls through to .then --> error function, even though the backend call to the serve succeeds end to end (status -1). Redoing the same request goes perfectly to .then --> success path.

I am using angular ng-view, ng-route and ng-controller constructs to thread my application.

Thanks for helping.

```
$http({
    url: "/api/v1/login",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data: {
        username: uname, 
        password: pword
    }     
 })
 .then (
    function (success) {
        $scope.content = success.data;
        if ($scope.content.status == "Login successful") {
            window.location.href="/apps/home.html"; 
        } else {
            alert("Login failed");
            window.location.href="#login";
        };
    },
    function (error) {
        alert("Call error = " + error.status);
        window.location.href="#login";
    }
 );
```

Comment: Could you check your browser's network tab and tells us what it says for that URL?

Comment: No I meant what status code are you getting for `/api/v1/login`. -1 doesn't sound right.

Comment: First (failing ) call is http://localhost:8080/#/ and the second (working call is) http://localhost:8080/?#/

Comment: The full error object is {error = Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: If it's making the call to `localhost:8080/#` then it's not making the call to `/api/v1/login`.

Comment: I probably did not answer your question. I am not sure how to look at browser's "network tab".

Comment: That is the strange part, I can trace the back end and see the call is coming in. But you did help me by bringing my attention to the missing ? in the URL. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the question mark should matter since on its own it doesn't add any query parameters, it's just a delimiter.

Comment: Experimented with and without ?. With ? always works, without does not. So some relevance for sure, even if it is not the root cause.

Comment: Response status -1 is not a valid/successful response status and that is why it is going in error callback of $http promise... Please revalidate your url, post data, or see if the service is up and running... If all looks good... Press F12 on your key board and this should bring up the developer tools of your browser... Now you can see console, sources, elements etc tabs... There look for 'Network' and lookout the RED url that is failing and check its request headers, body etc that whether it is going as expected

Comment: Yep, there is a red line on the network tab, It is my js: login (canceled) xhr angular.js:10765 0 B 19 ms. This is odd as even as the browser has this status, backend shows it received the request, processed it and sent good result back. The angular.js line in source is: xhr.send(isUndefined(post) ? null : post);

Comment: Try using the `$location` service instead of raw `window.location`. It is better integrated with the AngularJS `$q` service. A status of -1 indicates an internal AngularJS error. For more information on the `$location` service, see [AngularJS $location API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

Comment: OK, I will play with this later and report. Thanks all.

Comment: Did some experiments. It always fails when I set $locationProvider html5Mode true. It fails only the first time when mode is false. The only noticeable difference is in the URL (?# v/s #).

Comment: Another difference from the network tab for good v/s bad case is in good case the General --> Request URL is the correct one as localhost:8080/app/login.html and in the bad case it is the REST URL localhost:8080/api/login

Comment: Possible duplicate of [login using angular js and $http request not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550746/login-using-angular-js-and-http-request-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to close the loop on this. My issue was Action="#" in the HTML form. Removed that and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the raw `window.location` method with the AngularJS `$location` service. Calling `window.location` from inside a `$q` service fulfillment handler will generally result in an AngularJS internal error.

For more information, see [StackOverflow: login using angular js and $http request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35565999/5535245)