# login using angular js and $http request not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework, httprequest

I want to login using `$http` and `GET` of `REST web services`. What I am doing is:

1. Taking data on the basis of username and password using $http.get
2. Storing the result: `$scope.getResult=res;`
3. Storing it in some variable:

   var result=$scope.getResult;
   var username=result.userName;
   var password=result.password;
   var user=this.user;
   var pass=this.pass;
4. After that I will compare with the ng-model of username and password. If it is successful then it will redirect to another page like below:

   if (username == user && password == pass) 
    {
       window.location="/next.html";
     }

Below is my complete code and please suggest the changes required in my case.

```
$scope.login = function () {

  var user = this.user ; // ng-model of username in html page
  var pass = this.pass; //ng-model of password in html page  

  $http.get("http://localhost:17681/api/userRegisters"+user+pass).success(function (res) {

    $scope.getResult = res;

    var result = $scope.getResult;
    var username = result.userName;
    var password = result.password;

    if (username == user && password == pass) {
      window.location="/next.html";
    }

  }

}
```

Please tell me how should I change my code in order to do that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your url will be `"http://localhost:17681/api/userRegistersusernamepassword"`, put in some slashes

Comment: can you log the value of user and pass and see if the user and pass is actually there. Plus what you are doing with the url is sending a concatinated string of user and pass i.e. /userRegistersapplepassword. I don't think your api is expecting that.

Comment: Sorry , i am new to angularjs and i am not getting how to place filter in http url to compare the username in the database with the username entered

Comment: Also, when sending forms, especially with passwords, you should send them in a `$http.post` request instead of a get

Comment: thank you @devqon but i am not able to get you . can post some example or links where i can study that ? It would be very helpful.

Comment: please include your api method code that expects the data

Comment: are you talking about web service code ?

Comment: yes, the endpoint of your register user, the signature of that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the raw `window.location` method with the AngularJS `$location` service. Calling `window.location` from inside a `$q` service fulfillment handler will generally result in an AngularJS internal error.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:17681/api/userRegisters"+user+pass)
  .then(function onFulfilled(response) {

    $scope.getResult = response.data;

    var result = $scope.getResult;
    var username = result.userName;
    var password = result.password;

    if (username == user && password == pass) {
      //Use this
      $location.path("/next.html");
      //Not this
      //window.location="/next.html";
    }
}).catch ( function onRejected(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $location Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>

---

### Debugging the Response

> Its gives record via response.data but doesnt give column records. what should be done in order to fetch data ?

What is the specification for the server side API?

What is the server side code that generates the response data?

These are things readers will need to know in order to help you. Otherwise any answer is just a guess.

Industry best practice is to avoid sending passwords as a parameter of a URL as that has security issues.

Two resources recommended by the AngularJS team:<sup>[2](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide#specific-topics)</sup>

- [Deal with users authentication in an AngularJS web app](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app/)
- [Authentication in Single Page Applications With Angular.js](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/)

---

### Additional Resources

- [GitHub AngularJS Authentication](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication)
- [Bit of Tech: AngularJS Token Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)
- [AngularJS User Registration and Login Example & Tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much @georgeawg sir :) but when i alert username and password variable it doesnt show the username and password record from the Db table . Its gives record via response.data but doesnt give column records. what should be done in order to fetch data ?

Comment: Added section on debugging the response. And added resource links for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

"http://localhost:17681/api/userRegisters?username= " + username + "&password=" + password

and read the username and password from http://localhost:17681/api/userRegisters this location by using GET HTTP METHOD

Comment: I would recommend a POST instead and send the data in the body. Bad practice to put passwords in a url

Comment: Niyaz Thanks for the reply but this script is showing the whole database and not just for the given username

Comment: Yeah i agrre with the POST as it contains pssword , and i think the url doesnt exists... what the error says when u call ajax   $http.get("http://localhost:17681/api/userRegisters"+user+pass).error(function (err) {  console.log(err);  });